# Expected overlapping tags are missing

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm using the Html Agility Pack to parse some HTML, which can have overlapping tags.

Here's a simple method to do that:

```
public string Parse(string html)
{
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        doc.Save(sw);
    return sb.ToString();
}

input = "<b>bold <i>bold italic</b> italic</i>";
expected = "<b>bold <i>bold italic</i></b><i> italic</i>";
actual = "<b>bold <i>bold italic</i></b> italic";
```

A `TagNotOpened` parser error is also output on the `</i>`.

I have tried using `OptionOutputAsXml` as well as putting the input inside various other tags with no effect.

My expected result is that the word "italic" should be italic, but the tags should not overlap - it should be closed before the `</b>` and re-opened after. Is there any way to get my expected result either with HAP or a similar library?

Comment: What do you mean by _some HTML, which can have overlapping tags_ ? Overlapping tags are not well-formed HTML.

Comment: Overlapping tags are valid HTML in the same way as omitting </p> or not closing <br> is valid. They are not valid in XHTML, but if I always had valid XHTML I would not need to use HAP, I would just treat it as an XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) achieves the desired result and is still being actively maintained.

If this can't be achieved with Html Agility Pack, I'll mark this as the answer.